# Text File truncated by FTPClient

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I'm developing an Android App in which i connect and download a file from an FTP server using FTPClient object of the Apache Commons Net library, but on Android Nougat when i download the file,it gets truncated at half. The app is running great in Marshmallow. 
Someone can help me?
This is the code that works on Marshmallow:

```
    File app = new File(local_filename);
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.connect(ip,port);
    client.login(username,password);
    client.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
    client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(app));
    client.retrieveFile(filename,buffOut);

    buffOut.flush();
    buffOut.close();
```

Sorry for the bad english.

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can help you... unless you **post your code.**

Comment: You can output logs by `client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
`. I recommend you to check logs.

Comment: I checked the logs and the server return that the file is download properly

Comment: Try to use `client.retrieveFileStream()`.